# gravity affecting a molecules speed?

Tags: gravity, heat

Why are the poles colder than the rest ofthe planet?Is the gravity stronger making molecules spin slower?How does gravity affect heat and hydrogen bonds? And what affects gravity?A little off topic but Also, if you have alot of copper in your blood versus iron,does it affect your temperature?How does oxygen affect temperature?

Comment: There are way too many questions here, I suggest you focus on one particular question and show us what you already understand. I'll reopen this if/when you do that :)

Answer (score 2):

What @JerrySchirmer said about the poles.

I am answering the rest as if the question comes from a high school student.

> ?How does gravity affect heat and hydrogen bonds?

Heat is a collective phenomenon of the molecules composing a material moving about, in air, or vibrating in solids. The motion of molecules in air is affected by gravity since it is a continual force downwards. That is why there exists a stratification in the atmosphere from higher density near the surface to lower towards space. But gravity is very much weaker than the heat induced by radiation, and its effect will not be measurable in the temperature near the surface.

> And what affects gravity?

The gravitational field we feel at the surface of the earth at a specific coordinate depends on the bulk of mass radially down. There are variations in the gravitational field of the earth and this is a way of [learning about the density of matter](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2011/04/110406-new-map-earth-gravity-geoid-goce-esa-nasa-science/) in inaccessible regions in the earth.

[image: gravity map]

*a gravity map from the link*

> A little off topic but Also, if you have alot of copper in your blood versus iron,does it affect your temperature?

This is a question for biology.SE . Too much copper or too little copper affect the body. If you become ill then you might run a temperature.

> How does oxygen affect temperature?

If this is a biology question, it should be asked there. Oxygen molecules in the atmosphere have the temperature of the atmosphere. Oxygen is not a greenhouse gas, i.e. important in the heat retaining capacity of the atmosphere.

Answer (score 1):

The primary effect generating variations in temperature on a spot on planet is the amount of direct sunlight that that spot on the surface of the Earth gets.  The farther from the poles an area gets, the more direct sunlight it gets.